# How to properly override XmlHttpRequest to pass a custom key and value on headers

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I have been trying to override the XmlHttpRequest function to receive a custom header that it is stored on localStorage so at any request my custom header would be there. Also It would **ideal** that this could be achieved by using only vanilla JavaScript, without Jquery

I've tried to a class with the override method ,creating a prototype open and send methods using setRequestHeader to set the header

It should've overridden the xmlhttprequest native function now receiving the "UserToken" header

```js
class overrideXmlHTTPRequest {
  static override() {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('userToken')
    const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest()
    const xhrProto = XMLHttpRequest.prototype
    const origOpen = xhrProto.open

    xhrProto.open = function(method, url) {
      this._url = url
      return origOpen.apply(this, arguments)
    }
    xhrProto.send = function() {
      xhrProto.setRequestHeader('UserToken', token)
    }
  }
}

export default overrideXmlHTTPRequest
```

Comment: 1) What exactly is the question? I guess this code does not work? 2) What's the point of overriding when you can just add the header with `setRequestHeader()`. 3) I guess you're not using `fetch()` yet? Since that automatically has a headers parameter. 4) Can you show the code of how you call this? Something like `var request =  new overrideXmlHTTPRequest(); request.override();` ?

Comment: The code does not work properly, nothing comes on the headers how it supposed to; I've tried just using setRequestHeader("key" , "value") this function requires a Open and send method aswell, the native open and send method does not work for me; and i'm not using fetch(); I'm calling in my .Vue component using `HttpXMLRequestOverride.override()`

Comment: Have you figured out why: `var request =  new XMLHttpRequest(); request.open( 'GET', 'someurl' ); request.setRequestheader( 'UserToken', localStorage.getItem('userToken') ); request.send();` does not work? As specified in the docs, you have to call setRequestHeader() after calling .open(), else it won't work. So if native .open() and .send() do not work for you, I do not understand what you're trying to do by using them inside your override function, since `XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open.apply()` should not work either then.

Comment: Can you please show how you call this? Without knowing how you call `.override()`, we cannot make a mockup of your code to test it.

Comment: I'm calling in a vue component using `import HttpXMLRequestOverride from '../../override/HttpRequestOverride'` and later `HttpXMLRequestOverride.override()`

Comment: Your override function does not call .open() or .send() and does not return the xhttp constant, so how do you actually send the request then? You create a `new XMLHttpRequest()` after calling .override() in the previous step and then call .open() and .send() on that request? My advice would be to drop thinking about creating a wrapper around xmlhttp and just figure out why the initial code without this override complexity did not work.